# Pyomo Example Problems & Answers

Tags: pyomo

Are there any resources/textbooks that have lots of example problems and answers for Pyomo optimization problems?

I can find plenty of academic textbooks in R, AMPL textbooks and more.  However, I am struggling to find a Pyomo textbook, website, or other that has a collection of example problems and answers.

There are youtube videos that have diet and transportation problems, but these are limited.  Springer has a book by Bynum and Woodruff, but the style it's written in isn't what I'm looking for.

Thanks,

Comment: https://jckantor.github.io/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/README.html

Comment: This a great book   https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-68928-5

Answer (score 0):

I have been finding [this page](https://www.solvermax.com/blog/production-mix-model-1-pyomo) to be very helpful. It takes a single problem and, over several iterations, demonstrates various ways of formulating the model. I thought being able to see the incremental progress was particularly useful.

This [book](https://itslearningakarmazyan.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/operation-research-aplications-and-algorithms.pdf) also has plenty of examples. Though, if you didn't get on with the style of the Bynum and Woodruff, it may not be to your liking.

I also found the absolute [beginner playlists](https://www.youtube.com/@DrKatieRIT/playlists) on Dr Katie's You Tube channel to be very helpful too.